# Finding part of a string with regular expression

Tags: python

I am wondering how I can access a particular part of a string, namely I have a string as such.

```
tr|A0A2H1A6E1|A0A2H1A6E1_CANAR RNA polymerase III subunit C3 OS=Candida auris OX=498019 GN=B9J08_000927 PE=3 SV=1 UPId=UP000230249 PPId=UP000230249
```

I want to find the word between OS= and OX=, in the following example I would get Candida auris

I am aware that it can be done by regular expressions, but I am new to this and am not sure how I can make it happen. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
m = re.search('OS=(.*?) OX=', your_string)
print(m.group(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this without regular expressions:

```
line = "tr|A0A2H1A6E1|A0A2H1A6E1_CANAR RNA polymerase III subunit C3 OS=Candida auris OX=498019 GN=B9J08_000927 PE=3 SV=1 UPId=UP000230249 PPId=UP000230249"

subString = line.split("OS=",1)[-1].split("OX=")[0]

print(subString) # 'Candida auris '
```

*note that you may have to add some more code to handle cases where OS= or OX= are not present in the string (if that is possible)*

You could use a regular expression to extract all keyword=value pairs in a dictionary. this would make it easier to manipulate the result:

```
import re

pattern = r"((?<= )\w+\=(.(?!\w+\=))*)"
attribs = { k:v for kv in re.findall(pattern,line) for k,v in [kv[0].split("=",1)] }

print(attribs["OS"]) # 'Candida auris '
print(attribs["OX"]) # '498019'
```

Answer (score 0):

look behind and look ahead assertion:

```
import re

re.search(r'(?<=OS=).+(?=OX)', you_string)
# Output "Candida aurirs "
```

The match will be taken only if the keyword OS and OX will be found inside the string,
so you don't need to do other job on the captured string.

For any other suggestion and hint:
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html